# Redirect all subdomain URLs to matching main domain URLs - redirects with page paths not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache virtual hosts.

I have a Wordpress site: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Other sites commonly link to URLs such as:

- sub1.example.com/page1
- sub2.example.com/page2

I want to redirect them to:

- example.com/page1
- example.com/page2

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With both of these configurations, I get the following behaviour:

- sub1.example.com goes to example.com as intended
- sub1.example.com/page1 goes to a generic Apache 404 page "The requested URL was not found on this server." with the URL sub1.example.com/page1, it is not redirecting

My DNS setup involves A records pointing at the server IP for example.com, www, sub1 etc.

My virtual host .conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried adding sub1.example.com as a ServerAlias and reloading Apache to no avail.

How might I solve this?

Comment: The rule you implemented is fine, so you are either looking at cached results (did you _really_ make sure to prevent that? How?) or you have other, additional rules in place somewhere. Rewrite logging would allow you to understand what is happening inside your rewrite engine on a detail level. Take a look at the documentation how to enable it.

Comment: @arkascha pretty sure it's not cached, I've been using a few different redirect analyser tools. There shouldn't be other rules in place, I've just set up this site. I'll look into rewrite logging.

Comment: Do you subdomains even route into that directory you have the .htaccess file in to begin with? In your shown VHost setup, you have only specified `ServerName example.com` and `ServerAlias www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by creating individual virtual hosts for each subdomain, each with its own files structure and .htaccess file.